# SSRS 2008 R2 Have Row BackgroundColor inherit from Cell Background Color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm tweaking a reconciliation report and would like to be able to set the background color at both the row and the cell level.  At the cell level to highlight specific fields which are incorrect and at the row level to highlight when an entire record looks to be wonky (based on a handful of indicators).  However, when I use the `IIF(CheckForFields<>WrongValue,"Yellow","Transparent"/Nothing/"#FFFFFFFF")`, it still uses the Row BackgroundColor value instead of the Cell BackgroundColor value in the case the value is false.

Is there a way around this other than to add this as another IIF statement around the existing IIF statement within the Cell BackgroundColor Expression?

Comment: You can NEST your IIF statements like:
`=IIF(CheckForFields<>WrongValue,"Yellow", IIF(... ) ) `

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was suggesting with what I view as the last-place option.  Don't want to do that unless I have to because this is a fairly large report.